# Calling external HTML page inside Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i am trying to call a external HTML page to be displayed on website based on javascript conditions.

The code is like this

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://j.maxmind.com/app/country.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var country = geoip_country_code();

if (country == "US")
{
document.write("http://www.mywebsite.com/1.html");
}

else if (country == "GB")
{
document.write("<a href='#'><img src='http://www.image2.com' ><a/>");
}

else
{
document.write("<a href='#'><img src='http://www.image3.com' ><a/>");
}
</script>
```

Now, instead of showing the content of HTML page to US visitors, it just display "http://www.mywebsite.com/1.html" as plain text.

I am missing a function to call external HTML. Can someone help? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean the `<iframe>` element?

```
document.write('<iframe src="http://www.mywebsite.com/1.html"></iframe>');
```

Since `<iframe>` cannot resize itself to match the size of its content, be sure to give it a `width`/`height` attribute or style (if you know the actual size of content).

Answer (score 1):

Spitting the text of a URL into a page doesn't magically grab the contents of that page. This type of activity usually happens on the SERVER where your server will fetch the content from another page and serve it up as part of YOUR page. JavaScript is the wrong tool for this job.

Answer (score 1):

this kind of thing is really better to do server-side with stuff like php but here's a function I use in a lot of my commercial jobs. Again, I don't condone the use of this function for loading entire pages, but it's a really handy one to have in your toolbox. If anyone says you have to use JQuery to do this, kick them for me. ^_^

```
function fetchHTML(url)
{
  if( 'undefined' == typeof(url) ) return false;

  if( document.all ){
    p = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  } 
  else
  {
    p = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  rnd = Math.random().toString().substring(3);
  if( url.indexOf('?') > -1 )
  {
    url+='&rnd='+rnd;
  }
  else
  {
    url+='?rnd='+rnd;
  }

  p.open("GET",url,false);
  p.send(null);
  return p.responseText;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

well, you are giving a string to `document.write()` function, and that's why it is displaying the string that it was supposed to display. If you want to display content of some other page you have two choices either you can use an `<iframe>` or use ajax.